# Excel for Microsoft 365: Obtaining the Default Column Width

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using VBA in Excel for Microsoft 365.

I wish to obtain the default column width and store it in a `Double` variable. This is driven by the desire to not hardcode it. I have attempted to obtain this value as follows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

Dim columnStandardWidth As Double
columnStandardWidth = ws.StandardWidth
```

However, this returns a value of **8.11** rather than the expected **8.43**.

I have two questions:

1. How may I obtain the proper value of **8.43**?
2. What does the column width of **8.11** represent?

Comment: Is it possible in your debugging that you set the default size to 8.11 for that workbook?  Does the same code provide 8.11 for a brand new workbook?

Comment: Your code shows 8.43 for my default workbook. Have you checked the actual width of the columns in your new worksheet?

Comment: @squillman, I did not explicitly change the default size to be 8.11. However, to my surprise... It *is* 8.11 (under "Home-->Format-->Default Width..."). This is true for my current workbook as well as for a brand new workbook. This is true both in the Excel GUI (as just mentioned) and in the VBA code I showed above. I cannot explain this. For years, I've known the default width to be 8.43, and it now appears to be 8.11.

Comment: @Paul, the actual width of new columns in both my current and new worksheets is 8.11. I would have expected 8.43 as you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46#:%7E:text=Minimum%2C%20maximum%2C%20and,15.00), the default column width is 8.43. However this can can change based on your default font size as mentioned [here](https://o365sharepointblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/1260/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20column%20width%20has%20to%20do%20with%20default%20font%20size%2C%20and%208.11%20of%20a%20standard%20character%20fit%20in%20the%20column.) and is 8.11:

> The default column width has to do with default font size, and 8.11 of a standard character fit in the column.

In my case, the default column width is like yours 8.11.

> How may I obtain the proper value of 8.43?

Create a new template and customize it as described [here](https://thesoftwarepro.com/customize-excel-workbook/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a,are%20provided%20below.):

> To create a new default Excel workbook template:
>
> 1. Open a new blank Excel workbook.
> 2. Next, customize the blank workbook exactly as you want it to look.
> 3. Save the workbook with the specific file name in a designated folder.

On step 2, set the default width to 8.43.

Comment: I have created a template named book.xltx as described in the article you linked. I tried placing it in both directories listed in the article. I also tried placing it in the directory that auto-populated in the "Save As" dialog box when I selected a file type of .xltx. (That directory was C\Users\<user name>\Documents\Custom Office Templates.) In none of these three cases was I able to then create a new workbook whose default column width was 8.43. The default column width remained at 8.11.

Comment: @Dave This is how I did/do it: After opening a new workbook, CTRL+A to select the whole sheet, then Home -> Format -> Default Width : 8.43. I save the file as Excel template. Close excel or the file. Launch Excel, then open the template. When I check the width it's 8.44.